# How to re-enable Banshee icon in the older notification area?

Tags: indicator, banshee

I want to have the original Banshee tray icon back. How can I manage this?

The systray-whitelist is already set to ['all'], but without success.

All solutions I tried are workarounds and don't provide me the possibility to **rate songs** when the application is not in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to **Edit** --> **Preferences** --> **Extensions tab**, and then check   **Notification Area Icon**:

[image]

[image]